# It is not right I can't ask for a library advice

Tags: discussion, rules

I understand the basic motivation, you don't want programmers to give subjective response, it is right. And if the question would be simply "suggest me a library to parse xml" I would agree.

Neverthless, sometimes a programmer needs help in choice because they are searching for specialistic features. 
So, if the question would be "suggest me an xml library  which has to allow me to do this and that, without sacrificing that" I think it should be allowed.
As I am asking for a library with specific features and so subjectivity is limited.

I think the rule "don't ask for library advices" is too strict.

Answer (score 12):

You **can** now ask for recommendations about libraries. As long as you ask in the right place, and frame the question well.

The right place is the new [Software Recommendations StackExchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). For example, here's where I've got an open question, (as yet I haven't had an answer I can accept), where I'm asking for [a javascript library with particular features](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/801/353).

Please be very careful how you [ask](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/455/353) and [answer](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/353) there - read those two links, for the ground rules.